# How to send key '(' and '!' to Selenium Web Driver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java

I was trying to do write a test a case for a website that takes in the Java code , compiles it and runs it.
However, while writing the test case , the text-area that takes input did not have all the characters. I saw it was missing '(' and '!'.
I tried using the uni-code characters as well as ascii characters.

Here is code snippet:

```
   textarea.sendKeys("public class HelloWorld{public static String greet");
            textarea.sendKeys("\u0028"+"\u0029");
            textarea.sendKeys("{ return "+"\"hello world"+"\u0021"+"\";}}");
```

Output: "}}public class HelloWorld{public static String greet){return "hello world

I also believe '!' is making cursor to move to starting position.

Comment: Please refer answer and let us know if any query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to require basic understanding of Java. Java have some inbuilt functionality for converting this type of character.

**Solution :**

import `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;`

```
textarea.sendKeys("public class HelloWorld{public static String greet");
textarea.sendKeys(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\u0028") + StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\u0029"));
textarea.sendKeys("{ return " + "\"hello world" + StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\u0021") + "\";}}");
```

**Explanation :**

Here `sendKeys` is taking only string or character sequence arguments. So as per java definitions we have to pass value like that. `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\u0021")` convert value into java string. Please refer this question for more information. [Further Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126378/java-convert-string-uffff-into-char)

Please let me know If you have found any problems.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwile to look at the [source code for the Java KEYS class](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.java).

The characters you mentioned aren't readily available there, but you could implement any other character in a similar fashion.

An example of how to use the Keys class is found in [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629053/typing-enter-return-key-in-selenium). Of course, you can concatenate the Keys enum with string literals, as in your example.